Homoclinic orbits as critical points of an Hamiltonian
Good morning, I'm studying an article by P.H. Rabinowitz and he states that a critical point of given Hamiltonian is an homoclinic orbit for the associated system.
I don't understand why that is. Does anyone know why the given statement (highlighted) is true? What bothers me the most is why a critical point must satisfy the following condition:
$$
  \dot{q}(t) \to 0 \text{ as } |t| \to 0
$$
I'll send under here the piece where it's stated and the complete article. Thank you to everyone in advance and I apologixe for any possible typos.
Sincerely, Marco


